# Scrapy tutorial / Python cannot find the spider using VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scrapy

I am learning how to use Scrapy using VS Code using the original tutorial here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

However, when I want to run the spider I get the following error message: `KeyError: 'Spider not found: quotes'`

Here is the folder structure:

```
C:.
└───tutorial (scrapy.cfg is in here)
    └───tutorial
        ├───spiders (the spider is in here)
        │   └───__pycache__
        └───__pycache__
```

The code of the spider:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = f'quotes-{page}.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

And here is my `pip freeze`:

```
Automat==20.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2021.5.30
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==4.0.0
colorama==0.4.4
configparser==5.0.2
constantly==15.1.0
crayons==0.4.0
cryptography==3.4.7
cssselect==1.1.0
cycler==0.10.0
h2==3.2.0
hpack==3.0.0
html5lib==1.1
hyperframe==5.2.0
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==2.10
incremental==21.3.0
itemadapter==0.2.0
itemloaders==1.0.4
jmespath==0.10.0
kiwisolver==1.3.1
lxml==4.6.3
matplotlib==3.4.2
nose==1.3.7
numpy==1.21.0
pandas==1.2.5
parsel==1.6.0
Pillow==8.2.0
priority==1.3.0
Protego==0.1.16
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
pyOpenSSL==20.0.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
queuelib==1.6.1
requests==2.25.1
Scrapy==2.5.0
selenium==3.141.0
service-identity==21.1.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
Twisted==21.2.0
twisted-iocpsupport==1.0.1
urllib3==1.26.6
w3lib==1.22.0
webdriver-manager==3.4.2
webencodings==0.5.1
xlrd==2.0.1
xmltodict==0.12.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

This is how I try to run the spider: `scrapy crawl quotes`

So I checked if there are any packages missing but according to scrapy.org that seems not to be the case. Can you please tell me what I am missing?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the directory from which you are running the command? It should be ./tutorial/tutorial

Comment: I tried to run it from various directories:
./tutorial/ , ./tutorial/tutorial , ./tutorial/tutorial/spiders .
None of these worked.

Comment: You have tried this already, but to correct my comment. It should be ./tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my issue: Originally, I followed the scrapy tutorial and created the spider manually as a file in the spiders directory.

Now I deleted everything and recreated the project. This time, I created the spider using the scrapy command `scrapy genspider quotes http://quotes.toscrape.com` and altered the code of the spider according to the tutorial.

Now it is possible to run `scrapy crawl quotes` from the directory ./tutorial.